# Set SKTexture for SKSpriteNode with a given sprite.name

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I've been trying to run the SKTexture change from a node on touch, said node is created with a loop:

```
int nameIndex = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
       self.card = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"front"];
        NSString *nodeName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"node%d", nameIndex];
        self.card.name = nodeName;
        self.card.position = CGPointMake((((board-self.card.size.width)/3)*i), y);
        [self addChild:self.card];
        nameIndex++;
    }
```

In the touches began method I have:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:[touch locationInNode:self]];
    for (SKNode *node in nodes) {
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"node0"]) {
            //Change the texture for the given node:
            NSLog(@"Node 0");
            [self.card setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:nameIndex]];
        }
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"node1"]) {
            NSLog(@"Node 1");

         }
         if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"node2"]) {
            NSLog(@"Node 2");

         }
}
```

The touches began method works just fine, it runs the block as soon as one sprite is touched

however, as expected with the current code the texture change only occurs in the last created sprite. I've been looking for a way to run a method on a sprite with X given name, but I haven't fun a way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use the childNodeWithName instead of trying to force a conditional on the .name property

```
SKSpriteNode *card = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"node0"];
[card setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"aTexture"]];
```

Not sure if this is a helpful question, mods feel free to erase if needed.